# Different images appearing depending on input in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have a drop down list for a few cells within my Excel spreadsheet that has a few options. I was wondering if it were possible to show an image depending on which option was selected in the list. Ideally this image would show when you hover over it.

I have tried putting the image as a comment but comments are tied to the particular cell so you can't vary the image depending on the option shown.

Thanks.

Comment: >> Ideally this image would show when you hover over it. ??? Can you run that past me again?

Comment: So when you hover over the cell the image would appear. It's the same as if you have a comment on a cell; if you hover over the cell with the comment attached to it, the comment will appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. Here's the code below

```
If method = "Spaced" Then
    Range("B29").Select
    Range("B29").Comment.Visible = False
    Range("B29").Comment.Text Text:="" & Chr(10) & ""
    Range("B29").Select
    ActiveCell.Comment.Visible = True
    Range("B29").Comment.Shape.Select True
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Transparency = 0#
    Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Weight = 0.75
    Selection.ShapeRange.Line.DashStyle = msoLineSolid
    Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Style = msoLineSingle
    Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Transparency = 0#
    Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoTrue
    Selection.ShapeRange.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Selection.ShapeRange.Line.BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 225)
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.UserPicture "C:\Users\SESA363648\Pictures\Demo.PNG"
    Selection.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    Selection.Height = 60
    Selection.Width = 35
    Range("B29").Select
    ActiveCell.Comment.Visible = False
End if
```

To show multiple pictures you just have different checks and for that specific case you have a different picture